# values not post on onSubmit in angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular

### Detail

I am trying to post a form. In this form there are 4 fields Email, First Name, Last Name and Password. Now When I go to this URL `https://localhost:44300/Portal/register?invitekey=5e331c6176e24d3080f28b82a7a62f7a&email=donal@gmail.com` and now I pre filled the email fields by getting it from url which is disable. Now when form is load and I filled the remaining values and click on register button the data is post but email fields is empty in this case. but when I edit this email it successfully posted all the data. I have no clue what is wrong in this code. following is the code

### html

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                <form [ngFormModel]="registerForm" (ngSubmit)="onRegister(registerForm.value)" class="reg-page">
                    <input id="xss" type="hidden" name="idsrv.xsrf" token="model.antiForgery">
                    <div class="reg-header">
                        <h2>Register User</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div *ngIf="isError === true" class="alert alert-danger">
                        {{error}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group margin-bottom-20">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" [value]="email" id="username" placeholder="Email" autofocus
                               [ngFormControl]="registerForm.controls['email']" 
                               #username="ngForm" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group margin-bottom-20">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name" autofocus
                               [ngFormControl]="registerForm.controls['firstName']"
                               #firstName="ngForm" required/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group margin-bottom-20">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" autofocus
                               [ngFormControl]="registerForm.controls['lastName']"
                               #lastName="ngForm" required/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group margin-bottom-20">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" autofocus
                               [ngFormControl]="registerForm.controls['password']"
                               #password="ngForm" required/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <button [disabled]="!registerForm.valid" class="btn-u pull-right" type="submit">Register</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<style>
    .ng-valid[required] {
        background: #ceedce !important;
    }

    .ng-invalid {
        background: #fff0e0 !important;
    }

    .ng-pristine {
        background: #FFFFFF !important;
    }
</style>
```

### component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm }    from '@angular/forms';
import { FORM_PROVIDERS, ControlGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/common';
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';
import {  Router, ActivatedRoute } from  '@angular/router';
import { OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {UserService} from '../../services/user.service';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth/auth.service';


@Component({
    selector: 'register-user',
    templateUrl: '/app/components/user/register-user.html'
})
export class RegisterUserComponent implements OnInit {

    registerForm: ControlGroup;
    private sub: any;
    private inviteKey: string    
    private email: string
    private _data: Observable<any[]>;
    private input: boolean;
    constructor(
        @Inject(Router) private router: Router,
        @Inject(ActivatedRoute) private route: ActivatedRoute,
        @Inject(FormBuilder) private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        @Inject(UserService) private _userService: UserService,
        @Inject(AuthService) public authService: AuthService    ) {

        this.creatForm();
    }
    creatForm() {
        this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            'email': [''],
            'firstName': ['', Validators.required],
            'lastName': ['', Validators.required],
            'password': ['', Validators.required]
        });
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.router
            .routerState
            .queryParams
            .subscribe(params => {
                this.inviteKey = params['invitekey'];
                this.email = JSON.stringify(params['email']).replace(/"/g,"");
            });

        this._userService.handleInvite(this.inviteKey, this.email)
            .subscribe((data => {
                this._data = data;
            }),
            err => {
                console.log(err);
                if (err == "" || err == undefined) err = "Unable to Register."
            });

        console.log(this.email);
    }
    onRegister(value) {
        console.log("register form submitted");
        if (this.registerForm.valid) {
            this._userService.registerUser(value)
                .subscribe((data => {
                    console.log(data);
                    this._data = data;
                    let redirect = this.authService.redirectUrl ? this.authService.redirectUrl : '/login';
                    this.router.navigate([redirect]);
                }),
                    error => {
                        console.log("error while register User");
                        this._userService.handleError(error);
                    }
                );
        }
        else {
            console.log("Form is invalid");
        }

    }
    ngOnDestroy() {
        //this.sub.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

### image

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this ine of code in ngOnInIt `(<Control>this.registerForm.controls['email']).updateValue(this.email);`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is being caused by the field being set as readonly. First, try to remove the attribute and see if it works. If it does, you'll want to get the value using yourformcontrol.getRawValue(). Take a look at the documentation [here].[1](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#getrawvalue)